# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username') upon signing in

Tags: react-hooks

I keep getting this error when I log in with superuser, and I cant figure it out
It succesfully logs in, then the screen turn to error and then to blank screen.
This project is django-react, with users from django built in django-auth.
https://github.com/hypergeek-dev/mosaic_minds

```
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')

[https://github.com/hypergeek-dev/mosaic_minds/blob/main/src/auth/SignUpForm.js][1]
```

Comment: try to debug and see if you actually recieve the user's data after making an api/server call to retreive user's data.
1. Try to make sure that the component rendered after login correctly handles the user data. 2. Verify how user data is passed and used after login as the error may occur if user data is expected but not available. 3. Make sure all API calls or data fetching operations successfully retrieve user data, including 'username'.